# create a json path expression to get all the specific child elements, excluding the first parent

Tags: json, jsonpath

my json is as follows:

```
{ "a":[
        {
        "x":"1"
        },
        {
        "x":"2"
        },
       {
        "x":"3"
        }
       ],
    "b":[
       {
        "x":"4"
        },
        {
        "x":"5"
        }
       ],
     "c":[
       {
        "x":"6"
        },
        {
        "x":"7"
        }
       ]
}
```

i know i can get all the x's by `$..x` but i do not want all x's. i am trying to avoid getting the values of x from first array that is "a". basically get all x's except the ones from the first array. and the number of times x can appear in each array is undetermined. 
i want my json path expression to be resulting in:

```
[
"4",
"5",
"6",
"7"
]
```

how can i go about it?